# Fastest way to get key with most items in a dictionary?

Tags: python, timeit

I am trying to find the fastest way to get the dictionary key with the most items. The two methods I have tried so far are:

```
def get_key_with_most_items(d):
  maxcount = max(len(v) for v in d.values())
  return [k for k, v in d.items() if len(v) == maxcount][0]
```

and

```
def sort_by_values_len(dict):
  dict_len = {key: len(value) for key, value in dict.items()}
  import operator
  sorted_key_list = sorted(dict_len.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
  sorted_dict = [{item[0]: dict[item [0]]} for item in sorted_key_list]
  return sorted_dict
```

The first method return the key with the biggest number of items, while the second returns the whole dictionary as a list. In my case I only need the key, just to be clear. After comparing these methods in this manner:

```
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
  get_key_with_most_items(my_dict) # sort_by_values_len(my_dict)
print("Time", (time.time() - start_time))
```

I have come to the conclusion that the `get_key_with_most_items` method is faster by almost 50%, with times 15.68s and 8.06s respectively. Could anyone recommend (if possible) something even faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is extremely simple:

```
max(d, key=lambda x: len(d[x]))
```

Explanation:

- dictionaries, when iterated, are just a set of keys. `max(some_dictionary)` will take maximum of keys
- `max` optionally accepts a comparison function (`key`). To compare dictionary keys by the amount of items, the built-in `len` does just the job.

Answer (score 0):

Use `d.items()` to get a sequence of the keys and values. Then get the max of this from the length of the values.

```
def get_key_with_most_items(d):
    maxitem = max(d.items(), key = lambda item: len(item[1]))
    return maxitem[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

for the max function:

```
max(d, key=lambda k: len(d[k]))
```

If you want the dict to be ordered, then use OrderedDict. I think technically your code will still work with regular dict, but that's a technicality based on the current implementation of Pythons dict - In the past regular dict would not have reliable order, and in the future it may not.

You could do this for example as a one liner to turn your dict into an ordered dict by value length:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda t: len(t[1])))
```